# a command to view result on matlab for the tarjan algorithm

Tags: matlab, tarjans-algorithm

I'm working on an implementation of the Tarjan algorithm in Matlab.
I use [this source code](http://glotin.univ-tln.fr/graphes/graphtook/tarjan.html) to determine the strongly connected components.
This is the result I got, how can I view the result with Matlab (a figure that determines the colored strongly connected components)?
What is the appropriate command?

```
G=[0 0 1 1 0 0 0;
   1 0 0 0 0 0 0;
   0 0 0 0 0 1 0;
   0 0 0 0 1 0 0;
   0 0 0 0 0 0 1;
   0 0 0 1 0 0 0;
   0 0 0 0 0 1 0];

tarjan(G)

ans =

 7     5     4     6     0     0     0
 3     0     0     0     0     0     0
 1     0     0     0     0     0     0
 2     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: What kind of visualization are you looking for? Looking at the [Wikipedia page on Tarjan's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm) there does not seem to be a standard figure. Please clarify.

Comment: a figure that determines the strongly connected components in color like in this [link] (http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/graphconncomp.html) but using the source code that I have already put. how can I transform the result to a colored graph which determines the strongly connected components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already an examle using coloring, all nodes listed in the first row are colored with the first color, all nodes listed in the second row are colored with the second color etc...

Comment: thank you for explaining how to read the result , now I just want to transform this result in a figure that determines the strongly connected components whith different colors, have you any idea how to do it

Comment: Use the example you linked, there is a coloring mechanism included. I explained how to modify it!

Comment: ok I figured out how to proceed. I do not know how to program in matlab, can you give me the line of code that perform the modification